# How to authenticate with a Facebook token?

Tags: feathersjs

I'm POST'ing to http://localhost:3030/authentication and trying to  retrieve a JWT and create a user model using Facebook oAuth. My client side is React and seperate to the API.

My body:

```
{
    "strategy": "facebook",
    "accessToken": "EAALOM2rXQ50BAL5vERqa6YTJzyKZAeG4Yd9ZBPuqHfRmFzOpsQiTHEc1uS1sBaot7V9F7JlufpAWqqJoHIG8RCghLdBIKssKRyQqMLxiHvCPTjVDXqaR1rM4FhEXk55nFU0ZBZBP2KNVOoDNAGUBtJAOKaUdbeszLE0gXxgoF0DWgZBsRfVsZBFRBenQLMZBwZCDPIF606aHrA0CdDrcTRqSbcJWZCSlYIMwZD",
    "facebookId": "10155772119707013",
    "email": "joshn@hotmail.com.au"
}
```

But I'm getting a HTML page response saying 'You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.'

Same issue @ https://github.com/feathersjs/authentication-oauth2/issues/22 if anyone has figured out a solution to this.

Comment: not exactly answering your question but this is how i did it https://medium.com/@jacobgoh101/social-login-with-feathersjs-back-end-f834e5017230 . hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token

My solution (inside authentication.js) is to extend a custom Passport strategy:

```
app.passport.use('facebook-token', new FacebookTokenStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        app.service('users').find({
            query: {
                facebookId: profile.id
            }
        }).then((userData) => {
            if (userData.data.length > 0) {
                return done(null, userData.data[0]);
            } else {
                app.service('users').create({}).then((data) => {
                    return done(null, data);
                });
            }
        });
    }
));
```